# Are there any points on the parameter plane that do not belong to any wake?

Tags: fractals, combinatorial-geometry, complex-dynamics

p/q-wake is the region of parameter plane enclosed by two external rays landing on the same root point on the boundary of Mandelbrot set main cardioid (period 1 hyperbolic component).

**Are there any parameter plane points c from the  from exterior of Mandelbrot set  that do not belong to any wake ?**

[image: Wakes of Mandelbrot Set to Period 10] Image from [commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wakes_of_Mandelbrot_Set_to_Period_10.jpg)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsQvr.png The proportion of external angles $[0,1)$ not covered by wakes of period $q \le P$ seems to tend to $0$ as $P \to \infty$.  I think the external angle of $c$ would have to be irrational (but I doubt it's even possible), I have no proof even for the rational case...

Comment: If an external angle is rational, it's either preperiodic or periodic.  if it's preperiodic, its ray lands on a Misiurewicz point and they're all in wakes; if it's periodic it lands on a parabolic point which is either attached to the period 1 cardioid, or else inside a wider wake attached to the period 1 cardioid.

Comment: @Claude Is it your diagram ? How it was computed?

Comment: I used GNUPlot with data emitted by a small Haskell program that enumerates the bulbs and totals the widths of the wakes (using exact Rational for calculations, before final conversion for output); see https://mathr.co.uk/web/m-primary-bulb.html which is unfortunately missing references to where I found the algorithm...

Comment: If an external ray with an irrational external angle lands on the cardioid, it will not be in any wake.  I don't know if any irrational rays land.

Comment: Siegel disc and Cremer points probably have irrational external angles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer with help of the expert, [Wolf Jung](https://www.mndynamics.com/):

Yes,  those parameters belonging to external rays that land on the [Cremer](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/cremer) and
[Siegel parameter points](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/siegel) in the boundary of the main cardioid do not belong to any wake.